# Jquery .prop("selected", "selected") doesnt work on ipad chrome/safari

Tags: jquery, select

I have a problem with this code :

```
$('#activity_filter_type_activity option').eq(1).prop("selected", true);
```

It works on classic desktop but not in safari/chrome on an ipad.
Can you help me ?

Comment: Are you working on a Mac, or on Windows? If you have a Mac, you should be able to connect your ipad to your laptop, and do some debugging to get a better idea of what the issue is.

Comment: i found a way to  use console on the ipad by including
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite-debug.js"></script>

$('#activity_filter_type_activity option').eq(1).prop("selected", true);
doesnt product any result

Answer (score 0):

try using ".attr" to checked this

```
$('#activity_filter_type_activity option').eq(1).attr('checked',true);
```

i found this solution in other thread, is the same problem
[.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)

Comment: it doesnt work too with 
('#activity_filter_type_activity option').eq(1).attr('checked',true);

Comment: and either ('#activity_filter_type_activity option').eq(1).attr('checked','checked');

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use:

```
$('#activity_filter_type_activity option').attr("selected", "selected");
```

This is slightly different than the other answers.

$(element).attr("checked") is used for checkboxes, and you are trying to select an "option" input.

Comment: i tried $('#activity_filter_type_activity option').attr("selected", "selected"); too and it doesnt work :(

Answer (score 0):

If you are still searching for solution... the best way is to use js not jquery. In my project i have something like this and it works perfectly

```
    checkboxTmp = document.getElementById($(this).data('check'));
    if (checkboxTmp.checked) {
        $(this).children('span').css('background-position', '0px 2px');
        checkboxTmp.checked = false;
    } else {
        $(this).children('span').css('background-position', '0px -22px');
        checkboxTmp.checked = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I get around `attr()` or `prop()` failing in Safari and or Chrome. Just check the `length` of the jQuery object and selector, if `:selected`

```
if($('#activity_filter_type_activity option:selected').eq(1).length > 0){
      // is selected
} else {
      // not selected
}
```